# how to convert javascript into angularjs custom directive service?

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

```
                    $(document).ready(function() {

                        var apiRevoSlider = $('.tp-banner').show().revolution(
                                {
                                    dottedOverlay:"none",
                                    delay:9000,
                                    startwidth:1140,
                                    startheight:700,
                                    hideThumbs:200,

                                    thumbWidth:100,
                                    thumbHeight:50,
                                    thumbAmount:3,

                                    navigationType:"none",
                                    navigationArrows:"solo",
                                    navigationStyle:"preview1",

                                    touchenabled:"on",
                                    onHoverStop:"on",

                                    swipe_velocity: 0.7,
                                    swipe_min_touches: 1,
                                    swipe_max_touches: 1,
                                    drag_block_vertical: false,


                                    parallax:"mouse",
                                    parallaxBgFreeze:"on",
                                    parallaxLevels:[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],
                                    parallaxDisableOnMobile:"on",


                                    keyboardNavigation:"on",

                                    navigationHAlign:"center",
                                    navigationVAlign:"bottom",
                                    navigationHOffset:0,
                                    navigationVOffset:20,

                                    soloArrowLeftHalign:"left",
                                    soloArrowLeftValign:"center",
                                    soloArrowLeftHOffset:20,
                                    soloArrowLeftVOffset:0,

                                    soloArrowRightHalign:"right",
                                    soloArrowRightValign:"center",
                                    soloArrowRightHOffset:20,
                                    soloArrowRightVOffset:0,

                                    shadow:0,
                                    fullWidth:"off",
                                    fullScreen:"on",

                                    spinner:"spinner3",

                                    stopLoop:"off",
                                    stopAfterLoops:-1,
                                    stopAtSlide:-1,

                                    shuffle:"off",

                                    forceFullWidth:"off",
                                    fullScreenAlignForce:"off",
                                    minFullScreenHeight:"400",

                                    hideThumbsOnMobile:"off",
                                    hideNavDelayOnMobile:1500,
                                    hideBulletsOnMobile:"off",
                                    hideArrowsOnMobile:"off",
                                    hideThumbsUnderResolution:0,

                                    hideSliderAtLimit:0,
                                    hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
                                    hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
                                    startWithSlide:0,
                                    fullScreenOffsetContainer: ".header"
                                });

                        apiRevoSlider.bind("revolution.slide.onchange",function (e,data) {
                            if( $(window).width() > 992 ) {
                                if( $('#slider ul > li').eq(data.slideIndex-1).hasClass('light') ){
                                    $('#header:not(.sticky-header)').addClass('light');
                                } else {
                                    $('#header:not(.sticky-header)').removeClass('light');
                                }
                                MINOVATE.header.chooseLogo();
                            }
                        });

                    }); //ready
```

Comment: This is not a question... what have you tried, what are you attempting to do?

Comment: how to convert jquery in to angularjs please help me, in am trying to make a image slider in anguarjs that code is of javaScript........

Comment: That is jQuery. You really should work through some basic Angular tutorials, make an effort to learn. If you get stuck, please do post some of your code and we could help. You cannot expect people to simply write code for you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). This is not a free code-writing service nor tutorial site. You're expected to have already done basic research, to present the code you've tried with a description of how it's not working and what the expected result would be.

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ has a pretty easy to use built in directive for an image slider maybe you should try looking at that documentation

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Uk4JlZIRwn55Eqxtwqry?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

That may help you, btw if you had searched a bit you would have found it

```
 /**
 * Sample Directive
 */

define(['sampleLink', 'sampleCtrl'], function (link, controller) {
  function sampleDir () {
    return {
    /**
     * require is used by the link option
     * can be a single controller, or an array. '^myController', or ['^controller2', '^controller1']
     * controllers to be used in the link section. link (scope, element, attrs, requires)
     *
     * '^myController' - use ^ to search up the parents for the controller, otherwise it only looks at it's own element and will throw an error
     * */
    require : '',

    /* restrict what type of elements this directive is rendered on E=element <directive> or A=attribute <element data-directive> */
    restrict : 'EA',

    /* *
     * transclude in or outer scope. true = use the outer scope that this directive belongs to. false = create a scope inside the directive
     *      only use true when you want to create a directive that wraps arbitrary content
     *      when you use false and create a scope, you will want to pass in scope, or data through attributes on the element
     * */
    transclude : false,

    /* *
     * scope = create an isolate scope for the directive pass data into the directive through attributes
     *      This allows us to isolate the scope and reuse these directives throughout an app.
     *      =attr means to bind data to that attribute
     *      &attr means with transclude turned on this attribute will trigger evaluation of an expression in the context of the original scope
     *          any expression is allowed, including a function, this is ideal for binding callback functions to directive behaviors
     *          use this when we want the directive to expose an API for binding behaviors
     * */
    scope : {
        inputObject : '=inputObject',
        /*'close' : '&onClose'*/
    },

    /* templateUrl = Point to the template this directive should render */
    templateUrl : '/a/tpl/modules/util/input/inputs.html',

    /**
     * link : use link when you want to manipulate the dom with the directive
     * takes a function, inline or it can be dependency injected through requireJS
     * use the following signature function lin k(scope, element, attrs) { ... }
     *
     * scope is an angular scope object
     * element is the jqLite wrapped element that this directive matches
     * attrs is a hash object with key-value pairs of normalized attribute names and their values
     * */
    link : link,

    /**
     * Specify a controller, and use controllerAs to alias the scope, if you want to reference the scope or it's functions in the template.
     * You must define scope in the directive for this to be used.
     *
     * Q: What's the difference between controller and link? - A: Controllers can expose an API, and link can interact with controllers using require
     *
     * Best Practice: Only use controller when you want to expose the directive controller to another directive. Otherwise use Link
     *
     * This is great for building complicated directives that are made up of other directives and need to communicate with one another.
     * */
    controller : controller
    /*controllerAs : 'input'*/

}
}

return sampleDir;
});
```